# Angular backend routes for non-HTML resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to set up routing using `ngRoute` in Angular. I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558813/angularjs-routing-vs-backend-routing) that GET requests to the backend are supposed to return `index.html`, and then `index.html` loads Angular, which constructs the appropriate page.

But the problem I'm having is that GET requests to `app.js` are returning `index.html`. When I look at other peoples' code and old code of mine, they basically have the same route as me:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

For example, [this article](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-node-express/implementing-client-side-routing.html) seems to be addressing my situation, but I don't see how it handles the problem I'm having with non-HTML resources.

How are  you supposed to handle GET requests for non-HTML resources?

EDIT:

My file structure:

```
- algorithmsAssignments
  - node_modules
  - percolation
    - grid.js
    - main.css
    - main.html
    - main.js
    - uf.js
  - randomizedQueuesAndDequeues
    - main.css
    - main.html
    - main.js
  - app.js
  - home.html
  - index.html
  - server.js
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on port 3000...');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Comment: put app.use(express.,static.... before app.get('/*'....

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thanks. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what type of non-HTML resource you had in mind, you can have the express route return JSON like so:

```
res.send({ foo: 'bar' });
```

or the status code in addition to the returning of JSON

```
res.status(400).send({ Message: "not found" });
```

Not sure if it's relevant to what you're working on but you can of course load a non-html resource in Angular without ever needing to touch Express or to configure any routing:

```
$http.get('/myresources/configSettings.json').success(function (data) {
   if (data.foo === 'bar') {
      console.log('this works');
   }
}).error(function () {
   console.log('Error: failed to find your config settings.');
});
```

Comment: Basically, `index.html` has a bunch of js and css files that I need.

Comment: It's possible you might be over-thinking it. On the article you just linked they are defining their routes to dish up pages like 'Edit', 'Show', and back to 'Index', not to handle pulling in those scripts or stylesheets listed on their index page. You don't have to worry about Angular or Express helping you out with that stuff. Those files need to simply be able to be retrieved at the paths listed (relative or absolute).

Comment: Why isn't their `app.get('*')` catching GET requests to non-HTML resources, but mine is? EDIT: See comment to question, it's because of the middleware.

Comment: I'm not sure I can clearly follow enough of your site's configuration to answer that, but @lujcon is right that you configure express to handle static resources that way. But if you're trying to "route" to those resources listed in the index.html file or you're trying to manually request them, I believe that's a mistake. If you're simply wondering why resources listed in your index.html file don't seem to be loading, that's most likely going to be a pathing issue. But if you're trying to do something else with those resources I think I'd need to understand what that is a liitle better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't serve static files this way. Instead put all static files in one directory (ex. 'public') and add [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I'll recommend using custom routing for serving dynamic files only.

Comment: I'm using that middleware, see the edit to my question. I don't have stuff in a public folder though. Why would I need that? Note: everything was working before I made the backend route catch-all. Ie. when the route was just '/', everything worked except going to URLs directly.

Comment: You should put all static files in separate directory and should not mix server-side files with client-side files as through express.static middleware clients will be able to download your server-side source code. Currently you are able to download server.js form your browser - I don't think you want this.